# Python stops and chrome processes linger

Tags: python, robotframework

While running test cases built in the Robot Framework, at some point, the error “Python stopped” appears and I have observed that numerous chrome processes linger per Task Manager even when my test case closes all browser and performs a taskkill command.  As a result, my testing is suspended with aborting the only option.

Background and tech stack:

- windows 7/Windows 10
- Python 2.7.15/RobotFramework
- "scoped_dir*" directories fill up the disk space
- Chrome v74/chromedriver v74
- Chrome setting turned off:
      Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed
- Command line taskkill does not always work so only option is to end chrome process in Task Manager.

Test Setup      Run | `taskkill /f /t /im chrome.exe`

Test Teardown   Run | `taskkill /f /t /im chrome.exe`

Open Browser
......
Close Browser

Expected result:  chrome process stops running after each test case is executed and all `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dirXXXXX` directories are deleted.

Actual result: "Python stopped" is displayed; more often than not, numerous chrome processes linger and `scoped_dir*` fills up the file system.

Comment: that normally means that you have run out of memory. it could be that the script uses all your memory and is prematurely stopped which means it can't end cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Try killing the "Chromedriver.exe" as Robot framework uses chromedriver to interact with the chrome browser with the help of functions defined in back-end(Selenium library).

Try below Command in Test Setup
taskkill /f /t /im chromedriver.exe

Answer (score 0):

- I have already tried the taskkill command on chromedriver.exe and that does not work.
- I have increased the RAM on the computer and that does not work.
- I am running smaller suites of tests and that is working now.